# CORS configuration using nginx reverse proxy , ExpressJS and cloudflare

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, cors

I am working on a MERN website, so i got a vps, installed nginx on it to reverseproxy my API endpoint and configured my Cloudflare DNS records.

So am using a subdomain for frontend , and another one for api like this.

`https://api.mywebsite.com` for my api endpoint.

`https://front.mywebsite.com` for my frontend. (mywebsite.com is showing coming soon page , gonna change the front path to the main domain once i complete)

when trying to access frontend i got this error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mywebsite.com/apiendpoint' from origin 'https://front.mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The thing is i did add cors module to my app.js file and used it as middleware to allow access from front.mywebsite.com as i did add some configurations to nginx config file.

My app.js code :

```
//imports Here :
const express = require('express');
//const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

//declare app here :
const app = express();

app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views','Views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(cors(
        origin:process.env.FRONT_END; // i did try '*' here and i got same error
));


//Clients API Routes :
app.use(process.env.CLIENT_API_PATH,require('./Routes/clientAPIRoutes'));
//Admin Pages Routes :
app.use(process.env.ADMIN_PATH,require('./Routes/adminPageRoutes'));

// app.use('/',(req,res)=>{
//    //block main route access
//    res.send("Forbidden 403");
// });

module.exports = app;
```

where process.env.FRONT_END = https://front.mywebsite.com

And this is my nginx configurations :

```
server{
        listen 80;
        root /home/user/mywebsite.com/frontend/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name front.mywebsite.com;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        location /robots.txt {
                alias /home/user/mywebsite.com/frontend/build/robots.txt;
        }
}

server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  api.mywebsite.com;
     add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
     location / {
          proxy_pass "http://localhost:5555" ;
     }
}
```

What am i missing ? should i configure nginx only , express js only , or both of them so i can solve this issue . And could it be because am using cloudflare and how to fix it ?